# Restrict Azure User managed identity to be used only within a Subscription

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-managed-identity

We have several Azure Subscription under our organization tenant. I am trying to restrict UMI for the subscription. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to achieve it with using root management groups and assign identities to particular subscription. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/management-groups/overview) for more details.

Comment: Nancy Xiong..Can you please provide more details? The link does not show how to restrict UMI access

Answer (score 0):

To configure this setting in the Azure portal, follow these steps:

1. Use the search bar to search for and select 'Management groups'.
2. On the root management group, select details next to the name of the management group.
3. Under Settings, select Hierarchy settings.
4. Select the Change default management group button.

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/management-groups/how-to/protect-resource-hierarchy) for more details on UMI access.